# Sleep 1 second and then append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add iframes with waiting 1 second between adding each other, instead of adding all at once. Tried this with no luck, it just append it all at once.

```
var  i = 0;

function appendSomeItems() {
  for (var j=0; j<50; i++, j++) {
    $('body').append('<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>').delay(1000);
  }
  if (i < 50) window.setTimeout(appendSomeItems, 0);
}

appendSomeItems();
```

What is the correct way to do that ? thanks.

Answer (score 7):

```
for (var j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('body').append('<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>');
  }, j * 1000);  // each call is scheduled to run after j seconds
}
```

ps: do not use very large numbers or use setInterval with single function, counter and cleanup of the timer after the required number of calls was established or `setTimeout` the next call at the end of the current call of the timed function. Just skip that step at the last call.

Comment: Notice that he is using `j * 1000`. In this case this is needed because he is invoking all appends in one go. You don't want to append everything at once in 1 second, you want 1 item every second, so that is why he multiplies by the loop index. Next item will be appended in 0, 1, 2, 3 seconds and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the following code, which adds a new timeout after the previous one is finished. So you will never have multiple timeouts waiting.

```
var start=0;
var max=50;
function appendSomeItems(i) {
    $('body').append('<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>');
    if(i<max){
        setTimeout(function(){appendSomeItems(i+1)},1000);
    }
}
appendSomeItems(start);
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery's delay method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) is used for animations.

What you need to do is trigger the method every second. In order to do that you could write:

```
var itemsToAppend = 50;

function appendSomeItems()
{
    $('body').append('<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>');

    if (itemsToAppend--) // if 0 skips
        setTimeout(appendSomeItems, 1000);
}

appendSomeItems();
```